# How can I set today is date and specific time of the day in QDateTimeEdit in PyQt4?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

This is the code I have written:

```
dt = dt or self.cal.selectedDate()
date_time_str = str(dt.toString(QtCore.Qt.DefaultLocaleShortDate)) + " 10:00:00"
now = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(date_time_str, 'yyyy/M/d hh:mm:ss')
self.mydateTimeEdit.setDateTime(now)
self.mydateTimeEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
```

but this set date time to

1/1/00 12:00AM in the myDateTimeEdit UI.

when what I wanted is to set todays date with 10:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion to string is unnecessary, it is enough to pass it a QTime with the desired time:

```py
dt = dt or self.cal.selectedDate()
now = QtCore.QDateTime(dt, QtCore.QTime(10, 0, 0))
self.mydateTimeEdit.setDateTime(now)
self.mydateTimeEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
```